# Save and Load Data Model in Sench Touch 2.1

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Everybody!
I need to read and write a history data array.My data does loose data while page refresh. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use localstore in Sencha Touch, but it don't resolve my problem. My code like this:

console.log("====Check History====");
var history = Ext.getStore("HistoryTracking");
 // console.log(formValue.fieldTrackingID);
history.add(formValue.fieldTrackingID);
history.sync();

Comment: I want a something like cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by using LocalStore HTML 5.
With a some simple data, you can use:

```
var data = {};// data is a object just include text and value.
data = {"key1": value1, "key2": value2};// Example, i have a this object. 
//===> We save a object "history" by a string of "data" var. 
localStorage.setItem('history', JSON.stringify(data)); 
// ===> And get it: 
var retrievedHistory = localStorage.getItem('history'); 
// In Sencha Touch, you can parse this oject to your model. and Syns it.

var history = Ext.getStore("HistoryTracking");
history.removeAll();
var num = Object.keys(data).length;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
{
     var string = '' + data["trackID" + i];
            history.add(string);

}
history.sync();
```

Hope my sharing help you have same problem!